# Is `if x:` completely equivalent to `if bool(x) is True:`?

Tags: python

For a small testing framework we are writing I'm trying to provide some utility functions.

One of them is supposed to be equivalent to `if x:` but if that is **completely** equivallent to `if bool(x) is True:` then I could only provide one function to check `if x is True:` and `if x:`.

Is the negation of that also equivalent? `if bool(x) is False:` equal to `if not x:`?

Comment: Be careful. `if x is True` is not the same as `if bool(x) is True`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Care to expand on that? When would they not be equivalent?

Comment: Because `if x is True` is only true if `x = True`, but `if bool(x) is True` is true if `x = 1` or `x = ' '` or `x = [1,2]`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if x:` is *completely* equivalent to testing for the boolean truth value, yes.

From the [`if` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement):

> It selects exactly one of the suites by evaluating the expressions one by one until one is found to be true (see section [Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#booleans) for the definition of true and false)

where the [*Boolean operations* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#booleans) details how truth is defined. The [`bool()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool) follows those exact same rules:

> Return a Boolean value, i.e. one of True or False. x is converted using the standard truth testing procedure.

The Standard Types documentation has a [*Truth Value Testing* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an `if` or `while` condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below.

`not` simply inverts that same truth value; so if `x` is considered true by the above rules `not x` returns `False`, and `True` otherwise.

Be careful: in Python 2, the built-in names `False` and `True` can be *masked* by setting a global:

```
>>> True = False
>>> True
False
```

and thus `is` identity tests may be fooled by that re-assignment as well. Python 3 makes `False` and `True` keywords.

Your utility function should not need to use `bool(x) is True` or `bool(x) is False`. All you need is `bool(x)` and `not bool(x)`, as these *already* produce `True` and `False` objects. `bool()` and `not` can't return anything else, using `is True` or `is False` on these is extremely redundant.

Last but not least, try not to re-invent the testing wheel. The Python standard library comes with a `unittest` library; it has both `assertTrue` and `assertFalse` functions, and the [implementation of these functions](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/unittest/case.py#l412) just use `if` and `if not`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. These are equivalent. The rules used by `if` are the same as those used by `bool`. `not` simply inverts these values without changing the logic for determining truthiness or falseness.

Answer (score 1):

additionally to the answer of @Martijn, if what you are building are some class, you can define what behavior you want it to have in a truth testing case like `ìf x` by defining `__bool__` function.

```
>>> class A:
        pass

>>> a=A()
>>> if a:
        print("this instance class is truthish")

this instance class is truthish
>>> a is True
False
>>> bool(a) is True
True
>>>
```

the default behavior for a user defined class is to always be true in a truth test, to change that just define `__bool__` (`__nonzero__` in python 2) so it adjust accordingly to the semantic of the class, like for example:

```
>>> class Switch:
        def __init__(self, state="off"):
            self.state = state
        def __bool__(self):
            if self.state == "on":
                return True
            return False


>>> x=Switch()
>>> if x:
        print("this instance class is truthish")


>>> x is True
False
>>> bool(x) is True
False
>>> x.state="on"
>>> if x:
        print("this instance class is truthish")

this instance class is truthish
>>> x is True
False
>>> bool(x) is True
True
>>>
```